# How to prevent duplicates when populating an excel column from a userform input?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to prevent a user from adding a duplicate entry into an excel column. I found the way to set the column in excel but it doesn't work with the userform input.

I've tried the Data Validation setting in excel and they work, but when the input comes from the userform they do not.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strTargetColumn As String
    Dim nTargetRow As Integer
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String

    strTargetColumn = Split(Target.Address(, False), "$")(0)
    nTargetRow = Split(Target.Address(, False), "$")(1)
    nLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(strTargetColumn & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For nRow = 1 To nLastRow
        If nRow <> nTargetRow Then
          If ActiveSheet.Range(strTargetColumn & nRow).Value = Target.Value Then
             strMsg = "The value has been entered in the same column!"
             MsgBox strMsg, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Values"
             Target.Select
             Exit For
          End If
       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This is some code that I found during a web search that pops up that a duplicate was input into the column but still allows it to stay in the column.

I would like to have a popup tell the user they have added a duplicate, and not allow it to go into the cell. Is this possible?

[image: Userform]

Comment: Use `Application.CountIf` on the column before writing the value from the userform.

Comment: You have to add it to the userform code, not the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: BigBen I will research that. I'm still learning. Thanks

Comment: GMalc, Would I add that into the Userform_initialize or my add button?  I'm still a beginner sorry.

Comment: Just a pointer, add **@** sign infront of the name if you want to send a message to someone specific. That way they get a notification

Comment: Didn't know that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at it in the userform Click event for your buttons. Below is a way to do it for the Geometry button. You should always use Option Explicit to force variable declaration; your code implies you do not. Be explicit with your objects - don't use ActiveWorkbook, ActiveCell, etc.

There are lots of ways to improve this. It is not really a good way to do it. I provide this to get you going on a better track.

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit

Private Sub GeometryAddButton_Click()
    Dim theValueToAdd As Double
    theValueToAdd = CDbl(Me.theGeometryTextbox.Text) 'assumes the value is a double
    Dim theTargetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set theTargetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'assumes you want to use the book the form and code are in
    Dim theTargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set theTargetWorksheet = theTargetWorkbook.Worksheets("myDatabaseWorksheet") 'whatever teh name of your worksheet actually is
    With theTargetWorksheet
        Dim theGeometryColumn As Long
        theGeometryColumn = 1 'assumes the Geometry column is Column A (i.e. 1)
        Dim GeometryDataRange As Range
        Set GeometryDataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, theGeometryColumn), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, theGeometryColumn)) 'the full range of cells in Geometry column
    End With
    Dim findExistingValue As Range
    Set findExistingValue = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next 'if the value isn't found the Find method will fail, but that is what we are going to test for
        Set findExistingValue = GeometryDataRange.Find(theValueToAdd, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not findExistingValue Is Nothing Then 'if the Find does not fail (i.e. findExistingValue is not nothing)
        'pop up the message that the value already exists
    Else
        'add the value to the list
    End If
End Sub
```